# Multi-selection attibute for configurable product

Tags: attributes, configurable-product, products-management

What I'd like to create is a product in which you can select for a specific attribute multiple values.

Lets say the product is a t-shirt, the attribute is color the attribute set are various colors.
The customer can choose, for one t-shirt, multiple colors, maybe using a checkbox list instead of the usual droplist in configurable products.

Is that possible?

Comment: Configurable product is used to select only one simple product from the available options. if you want to select multiple simple products you can go for a grouped product or bundled product.

Answer (score 1):

You can used grouped products instead of configurable products.

This is how it looks:

[image: example]

**Documentation:** http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/catalog/product-create-grouped.html

Comment: Thanks!
Is it possible to set a price for the group, in your case Set of Sprite Yoga Straps, and not for every option?

Comment: @kiltro no, the grouped product is technically just a single product page that adds multiple simple products to the cart. If you want a fixed price for a group of products, choose a bundle product instead.

Comment: Great!
Another thing, I've like 70 different option for the product. 
Using Checkboxes gives a very long list, not really nice.

Using Multiple Select instead show one nice box, but multi selection in this case is accomplished holding down cmd key.
I'm sure a lot of customer will not know this.
Is there some simple solution to get an "automatic cmd" key while clicking on the options?

Comment: I don't know of a simple solution, but I'm sure that can be done with a few lines of jQuery if you search for it :)

Comment: Is it possible to set min and max selected products when using multiple selection boxes?